# Prove that $F=\int_x^{x^2} \! \frac{\sin t}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$ is differentiable.

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that $F=\int_x^{x^2} \! \frac{\sin (t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$ is differentiable and on the interval $(1, \infty)$ and calculate $F'(x)$ for $x\in (1,\infty)$.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...and what have you done so far on this?

Comment: @Timbuc I have no clue on how to solve this...

Comment: it's hard to accept such an explanation. You should *at least* have studied differentiation, Riemann - definite integrals, primitive functions and the like. What **can you try** with all this ?

Comment: Leibnitz is your friend... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @copper.hat is Leibnitz aware of such a friendship?

Comment: @Ilya: Only in the best possible world...

Comment: Find in your textbook the standard theorem that states "every continuous function has an antiderivative".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(x) = \int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t} - \int_0^{x^2}\frac{\sin t}{t} = f(x)-f(x^2)$$
where $$f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}$$
is differentable and $$f'(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

Hence $$F'(x) = f'(x)-2xf'(x^2) = \frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{2\sin x^2}{x}$$

$\textbf{Update}$ (about differentability of $f$):
$$\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} = \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}=\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_x^{x+\Delta x}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt = \frac{1}{\Delta x}\cdot \Delta x \frac{\sin c}{c} = \frac{\sin c}{c}$$
where $x\le c \le x+ \Delta x$ (and also note that $c=c(x,\Delta x)$). As $\Delta x$ tends to 0, $c$ tends $x$, and using the continuity if $\sin x/x$, we get
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\sin c}{c} = \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

Comment: Writing "$\;f\;$ is differentiable" is almost  exactly the same problem as the OP asks.

Comment: " almost exactly " ?!

Comment: it means that the OP is asking about the differentiability of a function defined by a definite integral, and you assume that a function (your $\;f\;$ ) defined as a definite integral of exactly the same function as the question asks is differentiable. For me that's almost to assume what is being asked...unless you can prove otherwise, of course. After all I could be wrong.

Comment: @Mher How do you prove that $f(x)=\int_0^x \! \frac{sin t}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$ is differentiable?

Comment: @RobertMulen: Did I answer your quastion ?

Comment: @Mher yeah thanks!

Comment: This time I think the answer actually addresses the question. It would be perhaps good to add the theorem you're relying on in your third equality, but this is basic stuff. +1

Comment: @RobertMulen, if you find this answer helpful then you should upvote it and, eventually, *choose* it as the best answer (there are no more answers, anyway).